# Ocaml convert string list to string

Tags: string, list, ocaml

I'm pretty new to Ocaml and I'm doing a task where I want to convert string list to string ( string list -> string =  ) where It concatenates elements by adding a space in between. Also If its a leading element it also adds "" and it ignores the empty strings.

My code so far:

```
let rec join list = function 
  | [] -> ""
  | [e1] -> e1
  | ""::e2 -> join list e2
  | e1::e2 -> e1 ^ list ^ join list e2 ;;
```

Not sure If Its correct, however I can't even test it because I don't know how to fix the error and change the parameter since It says that It's expected to call a function with a string, not string list.

Also any additional tips on how to add "" ONLY on the first leading element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that with `String.concat`, but since you don't want to add space if you have an empty string, you have to `filter` first.

```ml
let join l =
  List.filter (fun s -> s <> "") l
  |> String.concat " "
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to allocate an intermediate list for nothing, you can use the following (as @Chris suggested in a comment):

```ml
let join l =
  List.to_seq l
  |> Seq.filter (fun e -> e <> "")
  |> Seq.fold_left (fun acc e ->
    if acc = "" then e else acc ^ " " ^ e)
```

Comment: If you're joining the string sin the list with nothing in between, why bother filtering out `""` strings in the list? Maybe `let join = List.fold_left (^) ""`

Comment: @Chris It was a typo, due to me trying to interpolate between what the OP asked and the code they provided. In the question, they want to add space between strings ignoring empty strings. I corrected the answer accordingly.

Comment: The first implementation now appends an extraneous `" "` to the result.

Comment: @Chris maintaining four lines of code seems to be above my capacities :) I've corrected it.

Comment: Ahem... you are going to hate me.  `join ["hello"; ""]`  => `"hello "` I think the correct conclusion to come to is just to use the second approach. Though for efficiency I would use sequences rather than generating an entirely new list with `List.filter`: `l |> List.to_seq |> Seq.filter ((<>) "") |> Seq.fold_left (fun i x -> match i with "" -> x | _ -> i ^ " " ^ x) ""`

Comment: Have an upvote for not using profanity, if for no other reason. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could just use [`String.concat`](https://ocaml.org/api/String.html#VALconcat):

```
String.concat " " ["foo"; "bar"; "baz"]
- : string = "foo bar baz"
```